# Layer error: Computation timed out

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification

I want to run object-based svm classification with Sentinel 1 and Sentinel-2 images, and for that I first segmented the Sentinel-2 images which worked well. But then I wanted to make classification with both Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 images and it throws me an error like that: Classified objects: Layer error: Computation timed out.

Here are the few things that I've tried so far:

- Changing the scale parameter for higher numbers.
- Applying to reduce function for classification to stacked image (Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2).
- Not to visualize things that I don't need so that I can save more memory.

But no luck. Since the script is too long I only added the scrip link below.

Here is the full script with the assets:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/dc3ac51bbd2d02bbe8f28a2e848648d7

Comment: A time out tells me that you are using GEE's "interactive" processing stack & calling `Map.addLayer` or `print` on a computed result. The interactive stack is intended for rapid development/testing. In this spirit, it will time out requests that take longer than 5 minutes to complete. For these long-running tasks you'll need to use the "batch" processing stack (export your result) before viewing it. For testing purposes, you can perhaps limit the region to a small area or use fewer bands/images. (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments#interactive-environment)